# How to create model objects via a submitted form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How to create model objects via a submitted form.
Like here is a model:-

```
class <-->(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    Student_Code = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    E_Mail = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    Date = models.DateField()
    Time = models.CharField(max_length=122, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Date)
```

I want to create a new model class in which I want to change <--> to a desired name from views.py.

Comment: Verifying that I understood you correctly, you want to dynamically create new models (aka, db tables) using a form?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to say!

Comment: It is not natively possible,  and for a good reason. Creating a new DB table have a lot of overhead and you will face many problems while querying for the relevant data.
What you probably want is possible in relational dbs (sql) using Many to One relations. If that sounds good to you, I'll post an answer explaining how to do that for you case.

Answer (score 0):

Creating new models (aka db tables) dynamically is not very common for relational databases, and most of the time can be solved instead by using good-old relations.

In your case, it looks like it can be solved with a Many to One relation. This is how it can be done:

Lets say you have a model named Student (guessed from your example)

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    student_code = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(max_length=122, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

And we want to separate then into different categories (lets say Math students and CS students), so we can query only CS students.

First approach can be to set them a new field that says what category the are a member of:

```py
class Category(models.TextChoices):
    MATH = "math", "Math"
    CS = "cs", "Computer Science"


class Student(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=Category.choices)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    student_code = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(max_length=122, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

Now we can get only CS students using:

```py
cs_students = Student.objects.filter(category=Category.CS).all()
```

But this is not good enough for you, because you want to create those dynamically using a view. So lets convert that to a Many to One relation:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    student_code = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(max_length=122, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

Now we can get only CS students using:

```py
cs_students = Student.objects.filter(category__name="cs").all()
```

But can also create new categories with:

```py
physics = Category.objects.create(name="physics")
```

Now you can add a new Create View for `Category` and you will be able to create new types of students and query them separately.

```py
class CategoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    fields = ('name',)
```

### IMPORTANT NOTE

Could not have ignored that it looks like you are storing passwords in plain text. **This can be a major security risk** and django already comes built-in with many tools to avoid it.

I suggest you have a look on [Abstract User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) and use it as a baseline for your model.

```py
class Student(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    student_code = models.CharField(max_length=122)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'name'
```

This will take care of password storing for you.